# if statement doesn't works with socket.io and mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, if-statement, socket.io

i want to check if some values on my mongodb database exist, but if not exist, give me an error, instead of a event.
This is my code:

```
   socket.on("bot_req_id", async function(data) {
       let db = mongoose.db("wumpusCave")
       let bots = db.collection("bots")
       let find = bots.find({data})
       if(find) {
           console.log(data)
           let bot = await bots.findOne({"id":data})
           console.log(bot)
           socket.emit('bot_res_id', {"name": bot.name, "description": bot.description, "avatar": bot.avatar, "id": bot.id, "invite": bot.invite})
       } else {
           socket.emit('notfound', "bot non trovato")
       }
   })
```

The error:

```
           socket.emit('bot_res_id', {"name": bot.name, "description": bot.description, "avatar": bot.avatar, "id": bot.id, "invite": bot.invite})
                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null
```

I use node.js
How i can fix that?
Thanks in advice and sorry for bad english!

Comment: cause all those methods are async

Comment: @underscore but i need the async method for findOne() function

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/

Comment: @underscore it's returns a promise if i not use async method (check my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67758717/mongodb-get-entire-document-from-a-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait for this to complete

```
let find = bots.find({data})
```

before using the result. If the variable "find" does return the expected value then the problem lies here

```
let bot = await bots.findOne({"id":data})
```

But I'm fairly certain it's the first thing. make a propper promise and wait for it like so

```
return new Promise(resolve => {
            mongo.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, async function(err, db) {
                let dbo = db.db("yourdbhere")
                // Do stuff here
                // Make sure to close the db connection after you're done!!
                resolve(true)
            })
```